# MPV OSC not working on attached window with --wid option

Tags: osc, mpv, wid

I run mpv.exe "video.mp4" --wid="hwnd of a notepad window" and the video played on the notepad window well. But I was noticed that OSC is not working. I moved mouse cursor on the window and pressed some keyboard shortcut but nothing worked. How can I summon and use osc on the attached window..? I am using mpv-0.33.0-x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

i am late, but i found a way. directly send or post mouse input you catched to window. Then osc will be appeared if you did not off osc. the doc said the window being played by mpv with wid option do not take mouse or keyboard input. so you should manage it by your own hand.